# wsl throws error when a GUI app is launched

Tags: windows, debian, gui, wsl2, wslg

I'm currently in windows 11 (22000.258) i tried running google chrome in wsl (debian distro) it throws me this error "[124:124:1015/185302.103087:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1400)] Unable to open X display."
I tried installing drivers installing wsl from windows store but still it throws same error. could someone look into this please ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this a freshly installed Windows 11 with a newly installed WSL/Debian?  Or did the WSL installation exist on Windows 10 first?  If it existed from Windows 10, is there a chance that something in the "old" startup (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) could be getting in the way?